# The type 'string' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this issue after upgrading angular version to the latest in my project:

The type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReportTeamFilter[]'

the problem is when I do searchOptions.BusinessLst = this.business.value;

```
business = new FormControl('');
var searchOptions: DelegateSearch = new DelegateSearch();
searchOptions.BusinessLst = this.business.value;
```

delegate.ts

```
import { ReportingFilter }
export class DelegateSearch {
public BusinessLst: ReportingTeamFilter[];
constructor() {}
}
```

reporting-model.ts

```
export class ReportingTeamFilter {

public Id: number;
public Name: string;
public Date: Date;

constructor(){}
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Issue seem to be here : business = new FormControl('');
You are giving an empty String the the formControl. Typing it would prevent from errors : 
business = new FormControl< ReportingTeamFilter[]>(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that angular's new typed form feature is responsible for the error produced. Nevertheless the feature probably did not work before during runtime, so I assume it's a good thing that the error is now thrown during development phase.

The error is the following:

- Your are defining `business = new FormControl('');`, which means that `this.business.value` will return a `string` (before typed forms it would return `any`).
- Here you are declaring BusinessLst as a different type: `public BusinessLst: ReportingTeamFilter[];`
- Now you are trying to assign the string to this array type here `searchOptions.BusinessLst = this.business.value;`

That's why the error is thrown. The types simply do not match. You should specify what the correct types are and your error should be gone. Unfortunately I am not able to help you with that, since I do not know the business logic behind these types.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting array of ReportingTeamFilter and instead of that you are receiving string.

Change BusinessLst to be type string

```
// From:
public BusinessLst: ReportingTeamFilter[];

// To:
public BusinessLst: string[];
```